# How To Abstract Similar Javascript Functions into One?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to find the best way to abstract away these three functions into one.

```
function displaySummary(data) {
  getMyElement('app__summary').innerHTML = data.summary;
  return data;
}

function displayTemperature(data) {
  getMyElement('app__temperature').innerHTML = data.temperature;
  return data;
}

function displayLocation(data) {
  getMyElement('app__location').innerHTML = data.location;
  return data;
}
```

As you can see, the three of them share the exact structure. The parameter is just a simple object with some properties.

What I would like to do is to be able to call one function with two arguments like so:

```
displayElement(data, 'location');
```

And have something like this run (note, this next one is pseudocode):

```
function displayElement(data, STRING) {
  getMyElement('app__STRING').innerHTML = data.STRING;
  return data;
}
```

How would you go about doing this?
ES2015 syntax is welcome too.

---

META: I'm aware that this question might be flagged as a potential duplicate of the questions below. Neither of these answer how to interpolate (if at all possible) a string to work as a property accessor, which is mainly how I 'think' this problem should be solved. I'm open to suggestions and edits to make this question a better one.

- [How to condense similar JavaScript functions into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027221/how-to-condense-similar-javascript-functions-into-one)
- [Combine 3 functions into one in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063215/combine-3-functions-into-one-in-javascript)

EDIT: @Bergi flagged as duplicate a question that didn't come in my search and that *does* solve this question. Should I delete this one?

- [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: What's wrong with your `pseudocode` - aside from `app__STRING` should be `app__ + STRING`?

Comment: Closures. The answer is always closures.

Comment: what @tymeJV said + `data.STRING` should be `data[STRING]`

Comment: @Bergi Your duplicate does answer this question. Should I delete this one?

Comment: @adeluccar You can if you wish to, but you don't have to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use square bracket notation for reading the property and string concatenation for making the selector

```
function displayElement(data, prop) {
  getMyElement('app__' + prop).innerHTML = data[prop];
  return data;
}
```

if the string does not exactly match the property name, you could pass a third parameter which is a function to look up the right property:

```
 function displayElement(data, propName, lookup) {
  getMyElement('app__' + propName).innerHTML = lookup(data);
  return data;
}
```

Calling it as

```
// Note: Different casing of Location vs location
displayElement(data,"Location", d => d.location);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp

So in this case your function would be:

```
function displayElement(data, STRING) {
  getMyElement('app__'+STRING).innerHTML = data[STRING];
  return data;
}
```